# Working with SVG using JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to create an [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) element and modify it a bit using JavaScript. Mostly adding attributes and so on, but it's not working.

Here's what I'm trying:

```js
const makeSVG = (path) => {
    const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    const viewbox = "0 0 40 40";
    const width = "40";
    const height = "40";

    const svgIcon = document.createElement("svg");
    svgIcon.setAttribute("xmlns", xmlns);
    svgIcon.setAttribute("viewBox", viewbox);
    svgIcon.setAttribute("width", width);
    svgIcon.setAttribute("height", height);
    svgIcon.innerHTML = path;

    return svgIcon;
};

const generatedSVGIcon = makeSVG(
    `<path d="M19,6H13V3a1,1,0,0,0-2,0V6H5a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5,5v4a5.006,5.006,0,0,0,5,5H19a5.006,5.006,0,0,0,5-5V11A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,19,6Zm-9,4h1a1,1,0,0,1,0,2H10a1,1,0,0,1,0-2ZM5,16a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,5,16Zm1-4H5a1,1,0,0,1,0-2H6a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Zm9,4H9a1,1,0,0,1,0-2h6a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Zm4,0a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,19,16Zm0-4H15a1,1,0,0,1,0-2h4a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Z"/>`
);

const element = document.getElementById("element");
element.append(generatedSVGIcon);
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

I'm not really doing anything fancy, just creating an `<svg>` element, and adding some attributes so I'm expecting it to work.

If I inspect the `<div>` (`<svg>`'s parent container), I'll see that the `<svg>` is there, and If I copy/paste it anywhere else, it works as expected.

[image: inspected element]

Here's the generated `<svg>` element (and that's what is expected to show):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
    <path
        d="M19,6H13V3a1,1,0,0,0-2,0V6H5a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5,5v4a5.006,5.006,0,0,0,5,5H19a5.006,5.006,0,0,0,5-5V11A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,19,6Zm-9,4h1a1,1,0,0,1,0,2H10a1,1,0,0,1,0-2ZM5,16a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,5,16Zm1-4H5a1,1,0,0,1,0-2H6a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Zm9,4H9a1,1,0,0,1,0-2h6a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Zm4,0a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,19,16Zm0-4H15a1,1,0,0,1,0-2h4a1,1,0,0,1,0,2Z"
    ></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG xml markup is part of a different namespace so requires a special 'createElement' function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS     
Example: document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg")

Comment: Whoops, looks like SO has stripped some characters from that NS URL in my example. Make sure and use the full URL :-P

Comment: @diopside Woah, that's interesting. OK, actually, you can use markdown in the comments. For code, try backticks, two backticks, and put your code between them. For URLs, it's `[title](URL)`. Anyway, why is the `<SVG>` element so special, isn't it just an element like the rest?

Comment: @diopside Also, thanks though. I tried it, and it worked. I spent literally an hour staring at the code thinking if I missed something, never really knew of the `createElementNS` method thing, gotta read about it anyway. Also, feel free to write an answer :-)

Comment: oh, neat! I have always wondered the same thing myself, tbh. There are, of course, hundreds if not more reasons why the XML parser needs to consider namespacing 'under-the-hood', but it seems like it would be quite trivial to have the "consumer-facing" API be essentially unified and treat them mostly equivalently, especially considering there is no tag name overlap between HTML / SVG / MathML

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript is quite messy honestly. For SVG, I thought `xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";` was going to do the job like that's how people write SVG in general.

Comment: these days it seems like most modern browsers don't even need the XMLNS attribute - but i still use it liberally, almost out of trauma.... a few years back i spent almost an entire week hunting down a bug that turned out to be due to some missing XMLNS attributes on 2 inline svgs (was only causing problems in iOS safari). never again

Comment: Creating new SVG DOM nodes (parent svg or child elements e.g `<path>`  always requires adding the name spaced method `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000', 'svg')` – otherwise the appended node is treated as HTML: You can inspect it via dev tools, but it can't be rendered. Simplified: the SVG content is just gibberish in a HTML rendering context unless you tell the browser you're introducing a SVG DOM. However you could use `insertAdjacentHTML()` for larger chunks of SVG if you don't need to attach event listeners.